# Hide show based on selected Radio Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I was experimenting with some JS for a form I have been working on. The aim is to hide if they  user has not selected yes. Here is where I am some what stuck at:
HTML:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rbMatchingGift" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="No"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<li id="shcompany">                 
    <label for="txtCompanyName">Company Name</label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCompanyName" CssClass="narrow" />   
    <label for="txtCompanyPhone">Company Phone Number</label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCompanyPhone" CssClass="narrow" />       
</li>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var shcompany = $('#shcompany'); 
    showHide();
    mgift.change(function () {
        showHide();
    });

    function showHide() {
        var mgift = $('#rbMatchingGift');
        var shcompany = $('#shcompany');

        if (mgift.val() == "1") {
            shcompany.show();
        } else {       
            shcompany.hide();        
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What is exactly your question? What does not work?

Comment: On your page (after you run/view it), do a right-click, view source.  You will see that the RadioButtonList looks very different once it has been rendered into HTML.

Comment: @tgolisch as he has written `ClientIDMode="Static"` so the id will not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rbMatchingGift" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="No"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<li id="shcompany">
    <label for="txtCompanyName">Company Name</label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCompanyName" CssClass="narrow" />
    <label for="txtCompanyPhone">Company Phone Number</label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCompanyPhone" CssClass="narrow" />
</li>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        showHide();
        $('#rbMatchingGift input').change(function () {
            showHide();
        });

        function showHide() {
            var mgift = $('#rbMatchingGift input:checked');
            var shcompany = $('#shcompany');

            if (mgift.val() == "1") {
                shcompany.show();
            } else {
                shcompany.hide();
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey @Win I made a slight modification to my code and I am now trying to do the samething just based on the options. So if they select option 1 then something appears, if they select option 3 something else appears.http://jsfiddle.net/robertpurpose/fyjjY/2/ The problem is that when i select either option 1 or two and they both come on and go away

Comment: I found few errors in your code. Could you please open a new question because the code is really changed, and it is not same as the original question anymore? Please also include what do you want to show/hide in each value = 0, 1, 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think to get the selected radio button you'd want to do something like this

```
var rblSelectedValue = $("#<%= rbMatchingGift.ClientID %> input:checked");
```

Comment: as he has written `ClientIDMode="Static"` so the id will not change.

Comment: Ya, could cut out the .ClientID bit. I just copied from some code I had up in front of me

Comment: This is actually referencing to an external JS and not on the page. I tried this based on what you sent:

Comment: if (mgift.children("input:checked").text() == "Yes")
    {
        shcompany.show();

    }
    else
    {       
        shcompany.hide();        
    }

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems I see is that variable mgift is defined in function showHide, but you are trying to assign an change event handler outside of it. Put the declaration after var shcompany.

Also, figure out what actual HTML you get rendered on the page and use correct selectors to get the elements you need.